# SWIFT MT 940 Parser/Converter

Tags: oracle, parsing, converters, edifact, swift-mt

I am working at the moment on Bank Statements Integration and I was wondering if there are any converters that can convert my Bank Statement in SWIFT MT940 format into other Bank Statements formats like:

- BAI2
- EDIFACT FINSTA
- ISO20022 CAMT052 V1 - camt.052.001.01
- ISO20022 CAMT053 V1 - camt.053.001.01
- ISO20022 CAMT053 V2 - camt.053.001.02
- ISO20022 CAMT053 V3 - camt.053.001.03

Or at least, a converter that can convert my SWIFT MT940 file into a simple standard format like CSV, XML etc.

FYI, I need these Bank Statements formats to proceed some tests on Oracle ERP Cloud.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info) tag is for the programming language.

Comment: I deleted it, thank you

Comment: Is there any update to the above question?

Comment: I came across few solutions like 
1. [http://www.prowidesoftware.com](PROWIDE-WIFE )
2. Swift Standard Base libraries - https://www.swift.com/our-solutions/compliance-and-shared-services/mystandards/mystandards-base-libraries/features